# C# MessageBox buttons and UI

Tags: c#, localization, messagebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MessageBox buttons - set language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930754/messagebox-buttons-set-language)

In my application I use windows message boxes for most of the messages. At start up I set the application culture like:

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");

The problem is that message box buttons are in English for my machine which has windows in English and in German for a machine having German windows.

Does CurrentCulture or CurrentUICulture afect messagebox buttons?

Comment: Have you created the appropriate localized resources for your supported languages?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803129/change-language-for-messagebox-buttons-text

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch the OS text messages by simply set the proper culture.

The UI language is unique for any Windows version, except for the Ultimate, which may install several languages, then choose whatever you want. However, I don't think you may switch runtime, though.